# Java - transaction management framework

Tags: java, transactions

Developing in a microservices environment I have a process which I can define as a transaction.
I started developing a transaction model that persists initial data, 
polls it and reports status by request (e.g. a progress bar in the UI).
I was wondering whether there are transaction manageners  FW or better practices for java I can use.

Thanks.

Comment: Your application server probably has an option to use JTA - select the option and you get transactions for free...

Answer (score 3):

There is [Java EE Transaction API (JTA)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html) which sets the standard.

Regarding implementations, there are several, you can see a list of open source ones on [maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/open-source/transactions).